# Three Buttons problems

Tags: java, function, button, onclicklistener

I'm having trouble making a 3-button verson of a simple button/Listener program that I found on Oracle (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
I figure I have to separate the buttons and their listeners into their own functions but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. This is going to be for a future project that I will be working on. If i can learn how to make three buttons work with this program, I'll be able to implement it in my future project.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and which part is not working exactly? Please provide the important part of your current work, otherwise the community can't help you.

Comment: You can easily add a separate `ActionListener` to each button. You can use a *lambda* to add the listeners if using Java 8: `button.addActionListener(event -> { /*code*/ });`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just switch on the event's source?

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == button1){
          ... do stuff 1... 
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == button2){
          ... do stuff 2... 
        }
    }
```